# Private key and wildcard certificates

Tags: tls, public-key-infrastructure, heartbleed

I'm trying to understand the implications of private key leakage (due to Heartbleed) from a website that uses a wildcard certificate.

If an organization has a wildcard certificate (valid for *.domain.tld), does it mean that all sites that use this certificate will have to share the same private key?

Comment: They MAY use the same certificate for any *.domain.tld. However, the problem with bugs like heartbleed is that, in case you get hold of the private part of the certificate you are able to intercept (read / modify) any *.domain.tld HTTPS traffic and it doesn't really matter what the originally used certificate is (unless HPKP is enforced).

Comment: @bayo15 You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They MAY use the same certificate for any *.domain.tld. However, the problem with bugs like heartbleed is that, in case you get hold of the private part of the certificate you are able to intercept (read / modify) any *.domain.tld SSL/TLS traffic and it doesn't really matter what the originally used certificate is (unless [HPKP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Public_Key_Pinning) is enforced).